# validates format with regexp in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, format

**My Requirement :**
  To Add validation to make sure that SITEMAP_URL keyword is always included in    search_engines.url and it should be of format http://www.example.com/

```
class SearchEngine < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, :ping_url, :uniqueness => true, :presence => true
  validates :ping_url, :format => {:with => /\=SITEMAP_URL$/}, :presence => true

end
```

Is the validation i have written is correct .

Answer (score 2):

The validation looks fine.

Except if you expect `/\=SITEMAP_URL$/` to interpolate it won't.

It will only match strings like;

- "http://some.com?q=SITEMAP_URL"

Is that really what you mean?

If you have

```
SITEMAP_URL = "/sitemap.xml"
```

Then you can say

```
SITEMAP_REGEXP = /\=#{SITEMAP_URL}/
```

But this will interpret the "." as any character.

So you need to use `Regexp.escape`

Pretty much

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape("=#{SITEMAP_URL}")+"$")
```

Should do what you want.